# Cómo encontrar elementos que no están realmente almacenados en un método que devuelva un objeto de tipo List?

Tags: java

Usando `AbstractList` quiero escribir un método `panel(int begin, int end)` que devuelva un objeto de tipo `List` que contenga todos los elementos de un intervalo. Sin embargo, no quiero almacenar todos los elementos de la lista en realidad, sino solo encontrarlos usando los dos terminales dados en el argumento.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> l = panel(3,6);
    for(int i:l){
        System.out.println(i); //debe devolver 3 4 5 6 5 
    }
    System.out.println(l.get(1)) // debe devolver 4
}
```

Por lo momento hice :

```
public class Panel implements Iterable<Integer> extends AbstractList<Integer>{

   int begin;
   int end;

   // alguna lógica acá para llenar los valores de begin y de end, como constructor y/o setter y getter.
    public Panel(int begin, int end){
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;

    }

    public static List panel(final int begin,final int end){
        List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>();
        Panel borns = new Panel(begin, end);
        list.add(borns);
    } 


    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public T get ( int index ) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void add( int index, T e) {
        list.add(index, e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T o) {
        return list.add(o);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = panel(3,6);
        for(int i:l){
            System.out.println(i); //debe devolver 3 4 5 6 
        }
        System.out.println(l.get(1)) // debe devolver 4
    }
}
```

Pero no sé cómo encontrar elementos que no están realmente almacenados.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué pretendes hacer. Primero tu método *panel* no compila - falta **return**. Luego añade algo de código en el *main* para rellenar tu objeto (algunos add), si no es algo difícil ver por qué te devuelve *3 4 5 6 5*. Es más - dices que te devuelve 5 elementos y el intervalo *3, 6* debe tener solo 4. Luego no sé cómo quieres encontrar algo que no está almacenado ?!?! Muestra toda la lógica de tu clase *Panel*, tal como está no guardas los objetos en ningún sitio ¿verdad?

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Sí, lo siento, hubo errores.

Answer (score 0):

Lo iba a hacer en tu código pero tiene varios errores, pero sino me equivoco lo que tu tienes que utilizar [sublist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) de List, como muestro en mi código a continuación:

```
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numeros.add(0);
    numeros.add(1);
    numeros.add(2);
    numeros.add(3);
    numeros.add(4);
    numeros.add(5);
    numeros.add(6);


    List<Integer> sublista = numeros.subList(0, 6+1);  //Todos

    for(Integer numero: sublista) {
        System.out.println(numero);
    }


    System.out.println("------------");
    List<Integer> sublista1 = numeros.subList(3, 6+1);  //3 4 5 6

    for(Integer numero: sublista1) {
        System.out.println(numero);
    }
```

Resultado:

0

1

2

3

4

5

6

---

3

4

5

6

Comment: No, lo que quiere es un generador iterable, que cada vez que lo llames te de el siguiente número

Answer (score 0):

Dadas las especificaciones que expones, solo requieres redefinir dos métodos de AbstractList, y no sería mutable, insisto, dado como lo planteas.

```
public class Panel extends AbstractList<Integer>{
    private final int primero;
    private final int ultimo;

    public Panel(int primero, int ultimo) {
        if (ultimo < primero) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("parámetros inválidos");
        }
        this.primero = primero;
        this.ultimo  = ultimo;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return (ultimo - primero + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(int indice) {
        if (indice < 0 || indice >= size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("indice fuera de rango");
        }
        return (indice + primero);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Sin embargo obtengo un error: `cannot find symbol  this.ultimo  = ultimo;`

Comment: es que private final int ultimo lo había escrito como utlimo, o algo diferente, pero ya lo edité. solo cambié el nombre de private final int ultimo, que estaba mal escrito.

Comment: Y como plantea el método `panel(int begin, int end)` que devuelva un objeto de tipo `List` ?

Comment: No necesitas un método panel(int begin, int end). La clase Panel con su constructor crea una lista. Si quieres un método estático que te devuelva la lista solo tienes que retornar un new Panel(begin,end) en ese método.